# SFDX commands not working in VS Code

Tags: salesforcedx, error, vs-code, sfdx-error

I use VS Code for my pushing and pulling changes from org and branch and earlier I was able to use the SFDX commands but now I am not able to do so. Now when I try to run any SFDX command in the terminal of my VS Code it throws the below error :-

> /usr/local/google/home/ganit/.local/share/sfdx/client/bin/sfdx: line
> 16:
> /usr/local/google/home/ganit/.local/share/sfdx/client/bin/../7.110.0-85b006b/bin/sfdx:
> No such file or directory

and when I go to that file path mentioned in the error I find the below mentioned content :-

and I don't what this means as I do no the shell scripting language. What could be the issue with my setup? How can I fix this? Please help !!!

Thanks in advance !!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an [issue that's been reported](https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/1104). For now, potential solutions include downgrading to an older version or using the Node version (`npm install sfdx-cli`). Either way, try uninstalling and reinstalling.

> And yeah it is easily fixable if you just delete that folder and either reinstall it with the .pkg which will keep you on the auto-update track, OR use the Node version and it never updates automatically, you have to `sfdx update`

I personally use the npm version, it gives me an easy way to update on my schedule and generally avoids these kinds of random glitches that occur.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on a linux Box. I have download the sfdx-linux-x64.tar.xz and extracted it to a specific directory example sfdx. After adding export PATH=~/sfdx/bin:$PATH to the .bash everything works